# Ubuntu 22.04 login screen and display problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, display, 22.04, settings

I have a System 76 Oryx Pro laptop. I did an update and an upgrade approximately a week ago (3rd week of May 2022). After that, I started noticing strange problems.

When I reboot the machine, I enter my password and click Enter, but it takes 5 to 10 seconds to show the desktop. If I click anywhere on the login screen, the login fails, even if the password was correct.

Saving a file with vim also takes a few seconds, but closing a file that has not been edited happens instantly.

The brightness appears to change on its own, becoming slightly dimmer.

Since installing 22.04, I have not been able to use my second monitor. I am using the nvidia that says "tested" next to it. The second monitor has been plugged in for about a week but did not show up in the Display tab of Settings. Today, I brought up my Settings and it showed 2 monitors which it never did before. I've done no upgrades since then so I don't know what changed. My second monitor is an Asus, but Settings shows it as Ancor Communications. The second monitor suddenly works. But then I went out for a while and came back, entered my password and hit Enter and the built-in monitor remained blank and only the second monitor is working. Right now I am working from only the second monitor. I literally dragged my browser from a blank screen to working screen (couldn't believe I got so lucky without being able to see anything).

Is 22.04 not ready for real-world use yet? Was a bug introduced some time around mid-May? I have no idea what could be causing this. I am about to reboot the system right now. No idea what will happen this time, if either monitor will work at all. Any help would be very much appreciated.